# Looking for a tool or a script that will hide email addresses from PDF files

Tags: pdf, python, privacy

I am scanning the personal archive of someone and would like to publish the scanned files with email addresses hidden.

The PDF files have a text layer so it can be used to find the strings.

What I want is that the tool/script will find the string of the email address in the text layer, will delete the text and will place a black rectangle on top.

I don't expect any tool or script to do it perfectly.

Does anyone know of a tool or a script that does or can do that?

I am comfortable with processing PDFs with Python so if you think it's possible this way, I would love to get a link to an example I can modify for my specific use.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do it using [**PyMuPDF**](https://github.com/pymupdf/PyMuPDF).

See script example (from https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pdf-redaction-using-python/):

```
# imports
import fitz
import re
 
class Redactor:
   
    # static methods work independent of class object
    @staticmethod
    def get_sensitive_data(lines):
       
        """ Function to get all the lines """
         
        # email regex
        EMAIL_REG = r"([\w\.\d]+\@[\w\d]+\.[\w\d]+)"
        for line in lines:
           
            # matching the regex to each line
            if re.search(EMAIL_REG, line, re.IGNORECASE):
                search = re.search(EMAIL_REG, line, re.IGNORECASE)
                 
                # yields creates a generator
                # generator is used to return
                # values in between function iterations
                yield search.group(1)
 
    # constructor
    def __init__(self, path):
        self.path = path
 
    def redaction(self):
       
        """ main redactor code """
         
        # opening the pdf
        doc = fitz.open(self.path)
         
        # iterating through pages
        for page in doc:
           
            # _wrapContents is needed for fixing
            # alignment issues with rect boxes in some
            # cases where there is alignment issue
            page._wrapContents()
             
            # getting the rect boxes which consists the matching email regex
            sensitive = self.get_sensitive_data(page.getText("text")
                                                .split('\n'))
            for data in sensitive:
                areas = page.searchFor(data)
                 
                # drawing outline over sensitive datas
                [page.addRedactAnnot(area, fill = (0, 0, 0)) for area in areas]
                 
            # applying the redaction
            page.apply_redactions()
             
        # saving it to a new pdf
        doc.save('redacted.pdf')
        print("Successfully redacted")
 
# driver code for testing
if __name__ == "__main__":
   
    # replace it with name of the pdf file
    path = 'testing.pdf'
    redactor = Redactor(path)
    redactor.redaction()
```

Comment: Does this covers the sensitive parts with an overlayed layer, or does it actually change the embedded images? Can one use [`pdfimages`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pdfimages) to recover the original images (incl. the email addresses)?

Comment: Using redactions with PyMuPDF will remove the text **_as well as_** punch a hole in any image that overlaps the text (redaction) rectangle. So yes, data protection will happen all the way through.